# Comparing two lists for true and false

Tags: python, list, compare, boolean

for a program I'm writing, I have two lists at the end that I need to compare. They won't be in order, but here's the tricky part. At the end the first list may have more items than the second list. But as long as the first list has the required items defined in the second list, the function would return a true value. I tried set lists, but that's more for intersection, which is not what I'm looking for. This is the code I have so far:

this is the default player inventory, which is added to throughout the game.

```
pla_back = ["Combat Knife","Flares","Compass"]
```

this is the block of code that compares the two lists. I tried to use in, but it doesn't work.

```
acceptItem = ["Combat Knife","Flares","Compass","silver bar","a cloth","a stick","some rope"]
    if acceptItem in pla_back:
        placeholder
    else:
        placeholder
```

If someone could help me with this, I would very much appreciate it. I feel like the answer is right on the tip of my toungue, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if set(pla_back) >= set(acceptItem):
    print 'Player has the required items'
else:
    print "Player doesn't have the required items"
```

If my interpretation is correct, you want to see if `pla_back` contains all the elements in `acceptItem`. So it could have *more* but as long as it has each element in `acceptItem` it should return true.

Here `>=` means 'is superset'

```
s.issuperset(t)     s >= t      test whether every element in t is in s
```

So we're checking if every element in `acceptItem` appears in `pla_back`

Answer (score 1):

You should make at `acceptItem` a set. Then you can do

```
>>> acceptItem = {"Combat Knife","Flares","Compass","silver bar","a cloth","a stick","some rope"}
>>> pla_back = ["Combat Knife","Flares","Compass"]
>>> all(item in acceptItem for item in pla_back)
True
```

(This also works if `acceptItem` remains a list, but set lookup is much faster).